# How to add Flat View discussion board to web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, discussion-board

Currently, I'm having a Custom list and a Discussion board. Each item in the custom list is associated with one in the discussion board. 
The thing that I want to achieve is to:

- Insert the item in Discussion board into the associated item in the custom list
- The Discussion Board item should be displayed in Flat View.

Is there any way to achieve this?